# If $\lim_{x\to0} f(x) = L$ then $\lim_{x\to \infty }f(1/x) = L$ . Is the converse true?

Tags: limits

If

$$\lim_{x\to0} f(x) = L \implies \lim_{x\to \infty }f(1/x) = L$$

Is the converse true?

$$\lim_{x\to \infty }f(1/x) = L \implies \lim_{x\to0} f(x) = L$$

Why or why not?

So I think its true if I make $y= 1/x$ then it becomes lim $f(y) = L$ as $y $ approches $0$.

So it basically becomes the same thing right? I cant see why it wouldn't be true.

Comment: Please, next time, write the equations in the body of the post, instead of the title. That way they will be much more readable. Thank you.

Comment: Yes your idea is right, when the limit exists it is the same limit for the two expression, they are not different limits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that more in general since

$$\lim_{x\to 0} x=\lim_{y\to \pm \infty}\frac1y =0$$

we have that if $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)$ exists

$$\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)=\lim_{y\to \pm \infty} f\left(\frac1y\right)$$

since both expressions represent the same limit.

As noticed by Hans Lundmark we need to keep attention to the sign and we have that

$$\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)=L \iff \lim_{y\to \pm \infty} f\left(\frac1y\right)$$

but

$$\lim_{y\to +\infty} f\left(\frac1y\right) \implies \lim_{x\to 0^+} f(x)=L $$

$$\lim_{y\to -\infty} f\left(\frac1y\right) \implies \lim_{x\to 0^-} f(x)=L $$

Comment: Thanks for hint but only thing I can deduce from that is that it is true... I wanna know is there any case in which it won't be true

Comment: @EzioAltair What I'm claiming is that when the limit $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)$ exists it is always true that $$\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)=\lim_{y\to \infty} f\left(\frac1y\right)$$ that is $$\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)=L \iff \lim_{y\to \infty} f\left(\frac1y\right))L$$

Comment: And what if it doesn't exist? That's what the question is about.

Comment: @ArnaudD. Sorry could you please explain bettter why I'm not answering to the OP, I can't really see that. Thank you

Comment: @ArnaudD. Sorry the question posed is: is it true that $$\lim_{x\to \infty }f(1/x) = L \implies \lim_{x\to0} f(x) = L$$ therefore we are assuming that the limit exists. Am I wrong?

Comment: I understood $\lim_{x\to \infty }f(1/x) = L \implies \lim_{x\to0} f(x) = L$ as asking whether the limit exists and whether it is $L$. So to me you shouldn't assume that the limit exist. But perhaps OP was thinking like you.

Comment: Of course it is not true if and only if the limit doesn't exist (finite or infinte).

Comment: @ArnaudD. That's fine, sometimes we can understand something different from what the Op is asking therefore it is useful to have different points of view. Thanks again to have pointed out that.

Comment: Oh..okay.... Thank you so much guys.. :)

Comment: @EzioAltair To prove that (more) rigoursly you can proceed by the definition, it is an easy exercise!

Comment: Actually I'm very clumsy with the definition of limits

Comment: @EzioAltair That's not good if you want to get aware about that. I suggest to revise the definition and apply that. You can find many worked examples here on MSE.

Answer (score 3):

No, it's false. You can only conclude that $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0^+} f(x) = L$, since you don't know anything about what happens as $x \to 0^-$.

(Assuming, of course, that the question concerns functions of a *real* variable $x$.)

Comment: Ah yes of course if we consider, as usual, $x\to \infty$ as $x \to +\infty$. I revise my answer to clarify that point.

Comment: Oh... Thank you so much for clarification.